# GCM is not working on Nexus 7 it is on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So i have implemented GCM into my app with help of the AndroidHive tutorial.

The push messages used to work on both of my devices Samsung Galaxy S3 and Nexus 7. But now the push notifications only work on my samsung galaxy s3 and it gives an error to my Nexus 7. My nexus 7 does not want to register anymore. when i attempt to register my Nexus 7 i get this:

```
    01-01 07:46:33.396: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-01 07:46:33.396: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): GCM IntentService class: com.toviehd.remake.GCMIntentService
01-01 07:46:33.396: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 07:46:33.426: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-725930664821-1
01-01 07:46:33.426: E/GCMRegistrar(10980): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
01-01 07:46:33.426: V/GCMRegistrar(10980): Registering receiver
01-01 07:46:33.436: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-01 07:46:33.436: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:33.436: I/GCMIntentService(10980): Received recoverable error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:33.446: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 1573 (3000)
01-01 07:46:33.466: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Releasing wakelock
01-01 07:46:34.796: D/dalvikvm(10980): GC_CONCURRENT freed 212K, 5% free 8010K/8376K, paused 1ms+3ms, total 20ms
01-01 07:46:34.976: D/dalvikvm(10980): GC_CONCURRENT freed 273K, 6% free 8159K/8592K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
01-01 07:46:35.026: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
01-01 07:46:35.026: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): GCM IntentService class: com.toviehd.remake.GCMIntentService
01-01 07:46:35.026: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 07:46:35.036: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-725930664821-2
01-01 07:46:35.036: V/GCMRegistrar(10980): Registering app com.toviehd.remake of senders 725930664821
01-01 07:46:35.046: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Releasing wakelock
01-01 07:46:35.146: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-01 07:46:35.146: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): GCM IntentService class: com.toviehd.remake.GCMIntentService
01-01 07:46:35.146: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 07:46:35.176: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-725930664821-3
01-01 07:46:35.176: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-01 07:46:35.176: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:35.176: I/GCMIntentService(10980): Received recoverable error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:35.186: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 5157 (6000)
01-01 07:46:35.196: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Releasing wakelock
01-01 07:46:35.996: D/dalvikvm(10980): GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 6% free 8220K/8736K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 22ms
01-01 07:46:36.116: D/dalvikvm(10980): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 7% free 8332K/8868K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 24ms
01-01 07:46:40.346: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): onReceive: com.google.android.gcm.intent.RETRY
01-01 07:46:40.346: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): GCM IntentService class: com.toviehd.remake.GCMIntentService
01-01 07:46:40.346: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 07:46:40.356: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-725930664821-4
01-01 07:46:40.356: V/GCMRegistrar(10980): Registering app com.toviehd.remake of senders 725930664821
01-01 07:46:40.366: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Releasing wakelock
01-01 07:46:40.466: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
01-01 07:46:40.466: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(10980): GCM IntentService class: com.toviehd.remake.GCMIntentService
01-01 07:46:40.466: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Acquiring wakelock
01-01 07:46:40.476: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-725930664821-5
01-01 07:46:40.486: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE, unregistered = null
01-01 07:46:40.486: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Registration error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:40.486: I/GCMIntentService(10980): Received recoverable error: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
01-01 07:46:40.486: D/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Scheduling registration retry, backoff = 8885 (12000)
01-01 07:46:40.496: V/GCMBaseIntentService(10980): Releasing wakelock
```

I really do not know what i did to break this... Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It had to with a Date Time setting. The Date on the tablet was in the past. I think GCM can't sync into the past or something. I reset the Time on the tablet and it works again!!

Comment: Wasted my precious 10 hours figuring out what happened. Thanks a ton Toby.